# How to detect the MIME type of files and serve it accordingly using Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

Users can upload images to my site and name them (usually without .png or .jpg extension). This works when the image is served by an IMG tag. Apparently no MIME-type is necessary. The browsers can handle it because they *know* it has to be an image. When viewing the image directly, however, Apache serves the image as `text/plain`.

Now, I can use mod_rewrite to serve an appropriate MIME type, but how to write a rule to determine the MIME type of a file?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond something something involving grep, file, or whatever?
RewriteRule ^.* - [last,type=image/png]
```

My current solution which occasionally serves the wrong MIME type (with no harm done, apparently):

```
RewriteEngine on

# do nothing with .png, .jpg, .svgz, etc files                              
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .*\.....? - [last]

# add an image MIME type in order to force something other than text/plain  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [last,type=image/png]
```

Comment: Apparently I can simply provide any kind of image MIME type and browsers will handle it. Even if I provide `image/png` the JPEG images get rendered by the browser.

Comment: You mean to apply `type=image/png` to all requests that don't use an extension? In that case try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.[a-z]+$ [IC]`

Comment: Actually I want to figure out which MIME type to apply to all the requests that don't use an extension. On the command line, I'd use file(1) or look at the first few bytes of the file to figure it out. But within my .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache 2.4 has a dedicated module for detecting file types based on content:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html

```
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MimeMagicFile /etc/apache2/magic
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately `mod_mime_magic` is a global module:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line ...
MimeMagicFile not allowed in <Location> context
AH00526: Syntax error on line ...
MimeMagicFile not allowed in <Directory> context
```